# AND operator across nth dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is there an easy way to do an AND operation across n values in the xth dimension?

Example:

```
b = a(:,:,1) & a(:,:,2) & ... & (a:,:,n)
```

Version 2020a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `all` does this ([documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html)). It determines if all elements along one dimension are true (or non-zero).

```
b = all(a,3);
```

Comment: There’s also `any` for logical OR.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
x = 3;
b = sum(a,x) == n
```